# Draw a border around the active window in Gnome Shell

Tags: themes, gtk, gnome-shell

I am using the shellshape extension for tiling in the gnome shell, and the paper gtk theme by Sam Hewitt. I want to modify one small thing in the theme, that's I would like to draw a thin border around the active window. I believe this should be doable but couldn't find the proper resources.

Comment: I control theme border settings by editing `/usr/share/themes/{ThemeName}/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the correct place. Though I couldn't get my changes applied with <Alt-F2>+r, nor with logging out and in, for some reason.

Comment: I don't know at what point in the boot sequence GTK is initialised: I guess you need to do a full reboot.

Comment: GNOME Shell does not use Metacity theme unless you are using very very old gnome-shell / mutter.

Comment: Thanks, @muktupavels. This explains why I couldn't get it to work. Do you have any idea about how to do that?

Comment: @sencer by editing GTK+ theme and it depends on GTK+ version.